# In Selenium, I have an overlay that flashes on the screen for about 2 seconds and goes away

Tags: selenium

I have a simple web page I'm using Selenium to test. Well on load there is an overlay that pops up for about 2 seconds and then goes away. This is causing my FindElement to error out when it finds the element and tries to click it.

[image]

I can put a Thread.Sleep(2000) and that works fine, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If the overlay "disappears", you can check whether the overlay element is visible or not and wait until it disappears before proceeding with the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but is there a better way to do this?

I can think of one, yes.

You could do something like:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("overlay"))
```

this will wait until that overlay is hidden.  that up there is just pseudo-code so you'll need to tailer it to your specific language binding, and possibly add a check to see "if it's there, THEN wait. if not, don't worry about it"